# python - extract number from image get exact number

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

so i want to extract number from these 2 images
first image
[image]

second image [image]

i use this code i got from member here, this the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

im_path="E:/"
im_name = "test2.jpg"

# Read Image and Crop Borders
img = cv2.imread(im_path+im_name)[3:-2, 5:]

# Threshold on Red Channel
th=185
img[img[...,2]>th]=0

# Gray Color
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Thresholding
binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Resize as original image is small 
scale_ = 5 # of original size
width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_ )
height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_ )
dim = (width, height)
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(binary, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# Morhpological Erosion
resized = cv2.erode(resized, None)

# OCR
txt = print(pytesseract.image_to_string(resized, config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789 -c tessedit_char_blacklist=. outputbase digits'))

# Visualization
cv2.namedWindow("output", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("output", resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
print(txt)
```

it works great for the 1st image, but not for the 2nd image eventhought the 2nd image is more clearer than the 1st image.

how can i improve this so i can get the exact number from these images?

i tried to change threshold, scale, change the pytesseract config but nothing works